# how to multiply two 3D matrices with each other in any programming language

Tags: 3d, matrix-multiplication

I want to know whether two three dimensional matrices can be multiplied together? If yes, How do I multiply two three dimensional matrices.
thanks.

Comment: Have a look at : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63074/is-there-a-3-dimensional-matrix-by-matrix-product

Comment: Thanks. That was quite useful! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok start simple with 2D if our matrixes are

```
[a11, a12, a13]
[a22, a22, a23]
```

where a13 is the x translation, a23 is the y translation.

we add on an extra row `[0, 0, 1]` so we have

```
[a11, a12, a13]
[a12, a22, a23]
[0  , 0  , 1  ]
```

We do similar with our b matrix. Now for the first position in the result we go across A and down B. We end up with....

```
[a11.b11+a12.b21, a11.b12+a12.b22, a11.b13+a12.b23+a13]
[a21.b11+a22.b21, a21.b12+a22.b22, a21.b13+a22.b23+a23]
[0              , 0              , 1                  ]
```

We can pass that 3x3 matrix into other functions and when we come to render, we simply ignore the bottom row. A 3D matrix is just an extension of this idea, so your matrix is 4x4 with a bottom row of `[0, 0, 0, 1]`

Comment: There are also quaternions which are another way to represent orientation in 3D space.